# JAX-WS Payload mode exception

Tags: java, web-services, soap, jax-ws

I'm using JAX-WS in raw XML/Payload mode, and doing some validation manually:

```
@ServiceMode(value = Service.Mode.PAYLOAD)
public class WebServiceSimulator implements Provider<DOMSource> {

    private final String err = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?><soapenv:Fault><faultcode>soap:Client</faultcode><faultstring>Missing operation for soapAction</faultstring></soapenv:Fault>\n";
    public DOMSource invoke(DOMSource request) {

        if(errorCondition){
            return (DOMSource)new SimulatorDOMSourceImpl().fromString(err);
        }  
}
```

Everything works fine apart from the fact that the status is `200 OK`. How do I change the status message to something more relevant OR throw errors using exceptions? (if I use `RunTimeException()`, the SOAP client merely gets an empty response).

Answer (score 0):

You can  get the current instance of javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse form @WebserviceContext and you can put the error code in response object.

Comment: I've added `((HttpServletResponse)wsContext.getMessageContext().get(MessageContext.SERVLET_RESPONSE)).setStatus(500);` before the return statement, however I still get a 200 response